# How Do I Set User Agent In AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: java, android

In my app I am working with YouTube. I am requesting a page that I need in mobile view. Like this... http://m.youtube.com?persist_app=1&app=m
If I enter that link into a web browser I am locked in mobile view on the YouTube page (in the web browser that is). I want to do the same with AsyncHttpClient. If I was working with a webview I know I could do this..

```
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setUserAgentString("Foo/");
```

Now how do I accomplish this with AsyncHttpClient?

I've tried this and it didn't work

```
public void myAsyncHttpClient(String url) {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.addHeader("User-Agent", "Foo/");
    client.setUserAgent("Foo/");

    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

            urlHTMLCode = new String(responseBody);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
AsyncHttpClientConfig cf = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setUserAgent(UserAgentString).build();
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(cf);
```

Example with your code >

```
public void myAsyncHttpClient(String url) {

    AsyncHttpClientConfig cf = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setUserAgent("User-Agent").build();
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(cf);

    client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            urlHTMLCode = new String(responseBody);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I do not have a AsyncHttpClientConfig because it's red and it says "cannot resolve symbol". That's weird though because I have the dependency for AsyncHttpClient in my build.gradle.

Comment: Will someone please respond. I do not have the dependency for AsyncHttpClientConfig constructor. Thanks!

Comment: Have you included AsyncHttpClientConfig constructor in your java file ?

Comment: I'm not understanding this, I apologize. My app doesn't recognize what AsyncHttpClientConfig is and I am not sure how to add it or where to find it on Google. I've been trying to look this up and nothing is helping me. Is there another way that is easier that will accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand why client.setUserAgent can't do the same as new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder().setUserAgent("User-Agent").build();